# Вывод массива строк, который находится в структуре

Tags: visual-c++

Если пишу цикл вывода в функции initialization, то выводит, если в main, то нет

```
struct Deck {
    enum suit {heart, diamond, club, spade };
    enum value {six, seven, eight, nine, ten, jack, queen, king, ace };
    string deck[4][9];
};

void initialization(Deck *deck) {
    Deck objdeck;
    int i, i_2;
    string word_1, word_2;
    for (i = 0; i <= objdeck.suit::spade; i++) {
        if (i == objdeck.suit::heart) {
            word_1 = " of heart";
        }
        else if (i == objdeck.suit::diamond){
            word_1 = " of diamond";
        }
        else if (i == objdeck.suit::club) {
            word_1 = " of club";
        }
        else {
            word_1 = " of spade";
        }
        for (i_2 = 0; i_2 <= objdeck.value::ace; i_2++) {
            if (i_2 == objdeck.value::six) {
                word_2 = "Six";
                objdeck.deck[i][i_2] = word_2 + word_1;
            }
            else if(i_2 == objdeck.value::seven){
                word_2 = "Seven";
                objdeck.deck[i][i_2] = word_2 + word_1;
            }
            else if (i_2 == objdeck.value::eight) {
                word_2 = "Eight";
                objdeck.deck[i][i_2] = word_2 + word_1;
            }
            else if (i_2 == objdeck.value::nine) {
                word_2 = "Nine";
                objdeck.deck[i][i_2] = word_2 + word_1;
            }
            else if (i_2 == objdeck.value::ten) {
                word_2 = "Ten";
                objdeck.deck[i][i_2] = word_2 + word_1;
            }
            else if (i_2 == objdeck.value::jack) {
                word_2 = "Jack";
                objdeck.deck[i][i_2] = word_2 + word_1;
            }
            else if (i_2 == objdeck.value::queen) {
                word_2 = "Queen";
                objdeck.deck[i][i_2] = word_2 + word_1;
            }
            else if (i_2 == objdeck.value::king) {
                word_2 = "King";
                objdeck.deck[i][i_2] = word_2 + word_1;
            }
            else {
                word_2 = "Ace";
                objdeck.deck[i][i_2] = word_2 + word_1;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int i, i_2;
    Deck objdeck;
    initialization(&objdeck);
    for (i = 0; i <= objdeck.suit::spade; i++) {
        for (i_2 = 0; i_2 <= objdeck.value::ace; i_2++) {
            cout << objdeck.deck[i][i_2] << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Если Вам подошёл ответ, [отметьте его как правильный](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Вы передаёте в `initialization` ссылку на `objdeck`, но потом с ней ничего не делаете, а в ф-ии `initialization` создаёте новый объект `Deck objdeck;`, который заполняете, но он так "внутри" ф-ии и остаётся.

(Привёл несколько вариантов, какой из них лучше - не знаю, на C++ не пишу и слабо знаком с указателями)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Deck {
    enum suit {heart, diamond, club, spade };
    enum value {six, seven, eight, nine, ten, jack, queen, king, ace };
    string deck[4][9];
};

void initialization(Deck *objdeck) 
{
    int i, i_2;
    string word_1, word_2;
    for (i = 0; i <= objdeck->suit::spade; i++) {
        if (i == objdeck->suit::heart) {
            word_1 = " of heart";
        }
        else if (i == objdeck->suit::diamond){
            word_1 = " of diamond";
        }
        else if (i == objdeck->suit::club) {
            word_1 = " of club";
        }
        else {
            word_1 = " of spade";
        }
        for (i_2 = 0; i_2 <= objdeck->value::ace; i_2++) {
            if (i_2 == objdeck->value::six) {
                word_2 = "Six";
                objdeck->deck[i][i_2] = word_2 + word_1;
            }
            else if(i_2 == objdeck->value::seven){
                word_2 = "Seven";
                objdeck->deck[i][i_2] = word_2 + word_1;
            }
            else if (i_2 == objdeck->value::eight) {
                word_2 = "Eight";
                objdeck->deck[i][i_2] = word_2 + word_1;
            }
            else if (i_2 == objdeck->value::nine) {
                word_2 = "Nine";
                objdeck->deck[i][i_2] = word_2 + word_1;
            }
            else if (i_2 == objdeck->value::ten) {
                word_2 = "Ten";
                objdeck->deck[i][i_2] = word_2 + word_1;
            }
            else if (i_2 == objdeck->value::jack) {
                word_2 = "Jack";
                objdeck->deck[i][i_2] = word_2 + word_1;
            }
            else if (i_2 == objdeck->value::queen) {
                word_2 = "Queen";
                objdeck->deck[i][i_2] = word_2 + word_1;
            }
            else if (i_2 == objdeck->value::king) {
                word_2 = "King";
                objdeck->deck[i][i_2] = word_2 + word_1;
            }
            else {
                word_2 = "Ace";
                objdeck->deck[i][i_2] = word_2 + word_1;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int i, i_2;
    Deck objdeck;
    initialization(&objdeck);
    for (i = 0; i <= objdeck.suit::spade; i++) {
        for (i_2 = 0; i_2 <= objdeck.value::ace; i_2++) {
            cout << "[" << objdeck.deck[i][i_2] << "]" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
[Six of heart]
[Seven of heart]
[Eight of heart]
[Nine of heart]
[Ten of heart]
[Jack of heart]
[Queen of heart]
[King of heart]
[Ace of heart]
[Six of diamond]
[Seven of diamond]
[Eight of diamond]
[Nine of diamond]
[Ten of diamond]
[Jack of diamond]
[Queen of diamond]
[King of diamond]
[Ace of diamond]
[Six of club]
[Seven of club]
[Eight of club]
[Nine of club]
[Ten of club]
[Jack of club]
[Queen of club]
[King of club]
[Ace of club]
[Six of spade]
[Seven of spade]
[Eight of spade]
[Nine of spade]
[Ten of spade]
[Jack of spade]
[Queen of spade]
[King of spade]
[Ace of spade]
```

---

**UPD:**

Или можно так:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Deck {
    enum suit {heart, diamond, club, spade };
    enum value {six, seven, eight, nine, ten, jack, queen, king, ace };
    string deck[4][9];
};

void initialization(Deck &deck) {
    Deck objdeck;
    int i, i_2;
    string word_1, word_2;
    for (i = 0; i <= objdeck.suit::spade; i++) {
        if (i == objdeck.suit::heart) {
            word_1 = " of heart";
        }
        else if (i == objdeck.suit::diamond){
            word_1 = " of diamond";
        }
        else if (i == objdeck.suit::club) {
            word_1 = " of club";
        }
        else {
            word_1 = " of spade";
        }
        for (i_2 = 0; i_2 <= objdeck.value::ace; i_2++) {
            if (i_2 == objdeck.value::six) {
                word_2 = "Six";
                objdeck.deck[i][i_2] = word_2 + word_1;
            }
            else if(i_2 == objdeck.value::seven){
                word_2 = "Seven";
                objdeck.deck[i][i_2] = word_2 + word_1;
            }
            else if (i_2 == objdeck.value::eight) {
                word_2 = "Eight";
                objdeck.deck[i][i_2] = word_2 + word_1;
            }
            else if (i_2 == objdeck.value::nine) {
                word_2 = "Nine";
                objdeck.deck[i][i_2] = word_2 + word_1;
            }
            else if (i_2 == objdeck.value::ten) {
                word_2 = "Ten";
                objdeck.deck[i][i_2] = word_2 + word_1;
            }
            else if (i_2 == objdeck.value::jack) {
                word_2 = "Jack";
                objdeck.deck[i][i_2] = word_2 + word_1;
            }
            else if (i_2 == objdeck.value::queen) {
                word_2 = "Queen";
                objdeck.deck[i][i_2] = word_2 + word_1;
            }
            else if (i_2 == objdeck.value::king) {
                word_2 = "King";
                objdeck.deck[i][i_2] = word_2 + word_1;
            }
            else {
                word_2 = "Ace";
                objdeck.deck[i][i_2] = word_2 + word_1;
            }
        }
    }
    deck = objdeck;
}

int main() {
    int i, i_2;
    Deck objdeck;
    initialization(objdeck);
    for (i = 0; i <= objdeck.suit::spade; i++) {
        for (i_2 = 0; i_2 <= objdeck.value::ace; i_2++) {
            cout << "[" << objdeck.deck[i][i_2] << "]" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Или так:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Deck {
    enum suit {heart, diamond, club, spade };
    enum value {six, seven, eight, nine, ten, jack, queen, king, ace };
    string deck[4][9];
};

void initialization(Deck &objdeck) {
    int i, i_2;
    string word_1, word_2;
    for (i = 0; i <= objdeck.suit::spade; i++) {
        if (i == objdeck.suit::heart) {
            word_1 = " of heart";
        }
        else if (i == objdeck.suit::diamond){
            word_1 = " of diamond";
        }
        else if (i == objdeck.suit::club) {
            word_1 = " of club";
        }
        else {
            word_1 = " of spade";
        }
        for (i_2 = 0; i_2 <= objdeck.value::ace; i_2++) {
            if (i_2 == objdeck.value::six) {
                word_2 = "Six";
                objdeck.deck[i][i_2] = word_2 + word_1;
            }
            else if(i_2 == objdeck.value::seven){
                word_2 = "Seven";
                objdeck.deck[i][i_2] = word_2 + word_1;
            }
            else if (i_2 == objdeck.value::eight) {
                word_2 = "Eight";
                objdeck.deck[i][i_2] = word_2 + word_1;
            }
            else if (i_2 == objdeck.value::nine) {
                word_2 = "Nine";
                objdeck.deck[i][i_2] = word_2 + word_1;
            }
            else if (i_2 == objdeck.value::ten) {
                word_2 = "Ten";
                objdeck.deck[i][i_2] = word_2 + word_1;
            }
            else if (i_2 == objdeck.value::jack) {
                word_2 = "Jack";
                objdeck.deck[i][i_2] = word_2 + word_1;
            }
            else if (i_2 == objdeck.value::queen) {
                word_2 = "Queen";
                objdeck.deck[i][i_2] = word_2 + word_1;
            }
            else if (i_2 == objdeck.value::king) {
                word_2 = "King";
                objdeck.deck[i][i_2] = word_2 + word_1;
            }
            else {
                word_2 = "Ace";
                objdeck.deck[i][i_2] = word_2 + word_1;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int i, i_2;
    Deck objdeck;
    initialization(objdeck);
    for (i = 0; i <= objdeck.suit::spade; i++) {
        for (i_2 = 0; i_2 <= objdeck.value::ace; i_2++) {
            cout << "[" << objdeck.deck[i][i_2] << "]" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```